# Why Is After Effect So Slow?

Tags: adobe, after-effects

I have big problem with Adobe After Effect.  I have a fast PC with 32GB RAM, I7 Processor, 2 GB DDR4 VGA. Still, After Effect runs very slow.

What is the problem with My PC?

Answer (score 0):

First of all congrats for getting a mind blowing render monster for Aftereffects

Check these steps:

1. You can increase your Aftereffects application priority in the taskmanager(hope you are on windows machine)

   After starting up AE -> GOTO Taskmanager -> CLICK Process tab -> search for process having  with "AE" -> right click -> set priority -> (choose mong realtime,high etc)
2. Plz check following links

http://blog.templatemonster.com/2010/08/06/after-effects-8-ways-increase-productivity-render-speed/

http://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/improve-performance.html#improve_performance_before_starting_after_effects